# How to record from a keyboard using (A-B) type cable?

Tags: recording, digital-piano, computer

I have a *Privia PX-160* keyboard, and would like to record music and output the `MIDI` result to my device. I tried recording the music directly on my keyboard, and then transfer the `MIDI` file to my laptop (*Windows 10*). However, I saw that the file of the recorded audio is `.CSR` format, and I cannot play it or convert it to `MIDI` format.

So now the left option for me (I think) is to connect the keyboard to my laptop and record from a software like *Àudacity* while I play the keyboard.

I use this *USB cable (A-B)* type to connect to my laptop:

[image: USB A-B]

Can I record music with this type of connection, or is it just used for transferring files? The [*Audacity Tutoral*](https://manual.audacityteam.org/man/tutorial_connecting_an_instrument.html) does not show this cable for connection, only *RCA plugs*. My keyboard has *LINE OUT R, L/MONO jacks*, but I don't know if that's the same, since the User's Guide from CASIO only mentions connectivity to an Audio Equipment or Amplifier when using those jacks (not a device such as a computer).

Comment: The CSR files are indeed a proprietary format by Casio, and there seems to be no way to convert them to MIDI files.The PX-160 does not have audio-over-USB functionality, so you cannot record the audio output of the device over a USB connection. You can record the audio signal from the Line Outs by connecting them with an audio cable to the line input on your computer or to an external audio interface.

Comment: @Your I'll then buy a line out cable and try that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can transfer music using that cable, but not in the way you want to. You can use this cable for live MIDI transfer (so the computer can do a live recording of what keys you press or the computer can send key-presses to the keyboard that get played back just like if you pressed the key at that time) or for transfer of recorded files (which are also note sequences). You can not transfer the resulting audio waveform via the USB cable.

Comment: So with that cable I can only transfer live the keys pressed on the keyboard, not the actual audio. That also sounds interesting though. How do I do that?

Comment: For that, you need a to use a MIDI sequence program like Anvil, Cakewalk or Cubase. And pay attention to the manual page that explains how to switch between file transfer mode and MIDI mode.

Answer (score 1):

I created a tool to convert a CSR file to a MIDI file. You can try it here: https://github.com/tomerv/csr2midi

You will need to install Python on your computer first.

Comment: that's really cool! I'll check it out, thanks.